# Facebook Login Not Working in Android Ionic

Tags: android, facebook, ionic-framework, facebook-graph-api, ionic5

I have an ionic app with a facebook login feature.
The app is still in development mode. It works fine for ios platform with or without facebook app installed in ios device.

But for android, the facebook login works only when the facebook app is installed in the android device. When the facebook app is not installed in device and I try to login it shows me this screen [login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvW7m.png). After I click on continue nothing happens and my app becomes unclickable.

I am using facebook android sdk 12 so there is support for custom tabs as well.

I have followed all the steps like:

1. I have set all the urls like privacy policy & Data Deletion Url.
2. I have added both platform - Ios & Android.
3. I have added key hash in android section and set the class and package name
   appropriately.
4. I have advanced access for email & public_profile permissions.

My settings looks like the image [settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrILx.png)

Please let me know what can I do to make it work without facebook app installed.

Note: Also I am trying to login using the same account that has admin role in facebook developer console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in facebook sdk that I was using. Upgrading to any version above 14.1.1 will fix this issue.

Please refer the link : https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#1411